# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$encrypt_password' (T_VARIABLE) in your code on line 2

Tags: php, syntax-error

Hi I'm new to PHP but doing pretty well so far i think

I'm getting a syntax error on the line: $encrypt_ppassword=md5($newpass);

Can anyone help/tell me why?

```
<?php
        $id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            ## connect mysql server
                $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
                # check connection
                if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
                    echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->connect_errno} : {$mysqli->connect_error}</p>";
                    exit();
                }     
            ## query database
                # fetch data from mysql database
                $sql = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email LIKE '{$_POST['email']}' LIMIT 1";

                if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
                    $user = $result->fetch_array(); 
                } else {
                    echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->errno} : {$mysqli->error}</p>";
                    exit();
                }

                $username = $user['username'];
            if ($result->num_rows == 1) {
                $newpass = random_password();
                $newpass2 = $newpass
                $encrypt_password=md5($newpass);
$sql = "UPDATE users SET password = '{$encrypt_password}' WHERE id ={$id}";
                   if ($mysqli->query($sql)) {
                    $mailer->sendpass($username,$email,$newpass2);
                        redirect_to("forgot.php?msg=Reset Successfully");
                         }
        }  
        else {
                echo "<p>Sorry, no user found with this email.</p>";
            }
        }

                    if(isset($_GET['msg'])) {
    echo "<p style='color:red;'>".$_GET['msg']."</p>";
}
    ?>
```

For some reason I can get my changepassword page to work, my mailer to work and the encrypt function but when i put them all together they dont lol

Comment: Using user entered data directly in SQL queries causes SQL injection vulnerabilities

Answer (score 1):

The line before is missing a `;` at the end

Comment: Thanks, now the page shows except it doesn't work, when submitted correctly the page refresh's as if nothing happened

Comment: Insert "echo" statements for debugging to see which code paths are executed; StackOverflow is not a "please fix my code" page, please ask specific questions.

Comment: it's really annoying lol because it's not throwing me any error's, the page says it's done what its meant to do, it emails me but it doesn't update the database, anyway i will accept the answer for now if i find out how

Comment: Have you tried to `echo "$sql";` Maybe there is something wrong?